# How to avoid overflow in fast modular exponentiation

Tags: c, c99, integer-overflow

I am trying to solve a question on SPOJ which requires modular exponentiation. I am using the following C code

```
long long modpow(long long a,long long b,long long mod)
{
    long long product,pseq;
    product=1
    pseq=a%mod;
    while(b>0)
    {
        if(b&1)
            product=(product*pseq)%mod;
        pseq=(pseq*pseq)%mod;
        b>>=1
    }
    return product;
}
```

The problem is when I want to calculate `(2^249999999997)%999999999989`, it gives answer `0` because of overflow. How can I avoid overflow?

Comment: I don't think its avoidable unless you drastically change the implementation .

Comment: better use big number library like, gmp libmp...

Comment: int64*int64 's result need int128

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91583/implementing-fermats-primality-test/91584#91584 for the math behind computing remainders of large powers.

Comment: @mathk: Computing 2 to the 249999999997 would require a 249999999997 bit integer, which is a 29 gigabyte integer. I don't think a big number library is going to help.

Comment: @EricLippert Of course I don't mean to use it naively but use the same algorithm as the OP but instead of long change it to a biginteger. Avoiding the multiplication overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untestet, but you get the idea. This should work as long as `2*mod` is less than the maximum representable `long long` value and `a`, `b`, and `mod` are positive.

```
long long modpow(long long a,long long b,long long mod)
{
    long long product,pseq;
    product=1;
    pseq=a%mod;
    while(b>0)
    {
        if(b&1)
            product=modmult(product,pseq,mod);
        pseq=modmult(pseq,pseq,mod);
        b>>=1;
    }
    return product;
}

long long modmult(long long a,long long b,long long mod)
{
    if (a == 0 || b < mod / a)
        return (a*b)%mod;
    long long sum;
    sum = 0;
    while(b>0)
    {
        if(b&1)
            sum = (sum + a) % mod;
        a = (2*a) % mod;
        b>>=1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: +1 I tested this, and it gives me the same result as `pow(2,249999999997, 999999999989)` in Python.

Comment: I doubt this works for some values - e.g. `modmult(3, LLONG_MAX, LLONG_MAX);` (the `2*a` in `a = (2*a) % mod;` overflows causing undefined behavior and probably causing unintended negation).

Answer (score 0):

One additional suggestion is to make use of the fact that 999999999989 is a prime.
By using the relation, (a^n) = a % n (where n is a prime), u can simplify the operation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **unsigned long long** instead of **long long**, it will help you to play with higher values, whose range is 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Comment: GCC support __uint128_t. (128bit unsigned integer)